# Not able to find out xpath of button

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is the button's `HTML`:

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()">
  <span>
    <span>Continue</span>
  </span>
</button>
```

I would like to locate it via an xpath expression.  I've already tried:

```
//button[contains(@class, 'button')][contains(@onclick, 'shippingMethod.save()')
```

and:

```
By.xpath(".//[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button")
```

But neither work.

Comment: Is there any exception?

Comment: If none of the below solutions work, share the surrounding html code along with the error (are other elements available, wait, error log)

Answer (score 0):

Try using either of the below **xpaths**:

**1-**  `//button[@onclick='shippingMethod.save()']` 
  
This will locate the **button** having `onclick` attribute as `shippingMethod.save()`

**2-**  `//button[normalize-space(.)='Continue']` 
  
This will locate the **button** having innerHTML/text exactly equal to `Continue` with spaces (if present) trimmed.

**2-**  `//button[@onclick='shippingMethod.save()' and normalize-space(.)='Continue']` 
  
This will locate the **button** having `onclick` attribute as `shippingMethod.save()` and innerHTML/text exactly equal to `Continue` with spaces (if present) trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of these (preferably the second one since there might be multiple buttons on the page matching the same criteria):

```
//span[.='Continue']/ancestor::button[1]
```

Or

```
//span[.='Continue']/ancestor::button[@onclick='shippingMethod.save()']
```

Also you're missing a tag name or * in this

```
By.xpath(".//[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button")
```

Change it to:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button")
```

And it should work provided the button is the immediate child of the buttons-container element. If not:

```
By.xpath("//*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']//button")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the element on the webpage and click inspect
2. The HTML for the element should be highlighted
3. Right click on the highlighted section
4. Hover over 'copy'
5. Click Copy xpath

They're the steps to get the xpath from google chrome.

Answer (score -1):

One of the below locators can be of help

`//button[text()='Continue']` - find by substring

`//button[@class='button' AND @onclick='shippingMethod.save()']` -using AND

`//button[@class='button' OR @onclick='shippingMethod.save()']` -using OR

`(//button[@type='button'])[1]` - using Index, starts from 1.Trying changing index value

**eg: (//button[@type='button'])[X]
Here X takes index value.**

Comment: I think xpath index starts from 1, not from 0

Comment: The `text()` of the button isn't Continue... it's in the `SPAN`. Your `OR` option will match *any* buttons on the page.